# Blur function not being called

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I have the following code for sharing an article by email

```
function internalLabelBlur(elm) {
    if (!elm.value) {
        elm.value = elm.defaultValue;
    }
    if (elm.value == elm.defaultValue) {
        elm.className = elm.className.replace("internal-label-emph", "internal-label");
    }
} // function internalLabelBlur(elm)

function internalLabelFocus(elm) {
    if (elm.value == elm.defaultValue) {
        elm.value = "";
    }
    elm.className = elm.className.replace("internal-label", "internal-label-emph");
} // function internalLabelFocus(elm)

function z_onclick() {
    return false;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="emailErrEmailAddressArrow" class="errorarrow" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/error_arrow_signup.png" alt="sign up error arrow">
</div>
<input id="txtEmailAddress" name="txtEmailAddress" class="internal-label inputbox" 
    onfocus="javascript:internalLabelFocus(this);"
    onblur="javascript:internalLabelBlur(this);" 
    onclick="return z_onclick()" type="text" value="E-mail address*" />
```

The problem is the `onblur` function not being called. Can anyone help me as to why?

Comment: And how exactly are those functions called ?

Comment: via  onfocus="javascript:internalLabelFocus(this);" onblur="javascript:internalLabelBlur(this);" onclick="return z_onclick()" type="text"

Comment: @cmink I see nothing inherently wrong with this, but I would end the return statement in the click evt handler with a semi-colon to be safe.  Can you show the full markup of the element that you're binding to these event handlers please?

Comment: here is the entire string, i hope it answers your question. <div id="emailErrEmailAddressArrow" class="errorarrow" style="visibility:hidden;"><img src="~/Content/Images/error_arrow_signup.png" alt="sign up error arrow"></div><input id="txtEmailAddress" name="txtEmailAddress" class="internal-label inputbox" onfocus="javascript:internalLabelFocus(this);" onblur="javascript:internalLabelBlur(this);" onclick="return z_onclick()" type="text" value="E-mail address*" /><br />. where would i place the semi-colon?

Comment: What happens is that when i click on the envelop icon to share an article, i get the pop-up window but I cannot enter any info unless i keep the mouse clicked in it

Comment: seems like i figured out the prob is something else :(